# If two states of a DFA are k-equivalent and k+1 equivalent

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

Consider a DFA $A$ and $k\geq 0$. For states $q$ and $p$ of $A$, we say that $p\equiv_k q$ when $p$ and $q$ agree on all words of length at most $k$; that is, $p\equiv_k q$ when for all words $w$ of length at most $k$, it holds that $p$ has an accepting run on $w$ iff $q$ has an accepting run on $w$.
Then, we say that $q\equiv p$ when $q\equiv_k p$ for all $k\geq 0$.

Is the following claim correct?

**Claim:**
Consider a DFA $A$. If $q$ and $p$ are states of $A$ such that
$p\equiv_kq$ and $p\equiv_{k+1}q$, for some $k$, then $p \equiv q$.

I don't think so, because if the minimization algorithm can continue, $q$ and $p$ might be separate at a later iteration, am I correct?

Comment: Your question requires more elaboration.

Comment: Please define all notation, including what is meant by $\equiv_k$.  Have you worked through some examples to try to find a counter-example, say with $k=0$?  What progress have you made?  We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as they are unlikely to help others in the future.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Right, but you need to suggest a counter-example. Saying that the states might separate in the operation of a minimization algorithm is not a proof.

$p\equiv_k q$ means that for all words $w$ of length at most $k$, there is an accepting run from $p$ on $w$ iff there is an accepting run from $q$ on $w$. In words, there is no word of length at most $k$ that *separates* between $q$ and $p$.
Back to your claim, can you suggest a DFA that has two states that are $k$-equivalent and $(k+1)$-equivalent,  yet are not $(k+2)$-equivalent?

**Hint:** Start by considering $k=0$ and note that all accepting states are $0$-equivalent, and all rejecting states are $0$-equivalent.